# Как сделать срез данных с базы данных, которая находится в production?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, администрирование, devops

Предположим, есть структура БД.

Сотни таблиц, ключей, десятки индексов и т.п. Важно, что **структура БД в окружении разработки и в production одинакова** (достигаем этого миграциями).

Данные:
В production базе 100 ГБ данных. Слишком много, чтобы сделать дамп и дать разработчику для разработки, но вести разработку необходимо на реальных данных (я знаю про библиотеки генерации фейковых данных, вопрос не в этом).

Как выполнить срез (или как это грамотно назвать) небольшого кусочка (допустим, в 50 мб) данных для разработки, при этом сохранить все внешние ключи и целостность данных?

Comment: Может всё-таки дамп базы будет лучше? при дампе можно значительно сократить объем базы примерно на 90%. Посмотреть что и сколько занимает можно примерно так: `SELECT table_name, pg_relation_size(table_name), pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(table_name))
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
ORDER by 2 DESC;`, а вот при дампе указать для примера: `pg_dump dbname -Fc \
   --exclude-table-data 'logging*' \
   --exclude-table-data 'reversions*' \
   --exclude-table-data 'webhooks_logging*' > postgres.dev.sql`